Does BaseSettings support adding arbitrary input params without having to override the constructor?
In my Config class:
class MyConfig(BaseSettings):
    err_if_not_found: bool = False
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        env_file=MyConfigs(err_if_not_found).configs,
        env_prefix="MY_APP",
    )

I have my own class for loading configs and it supports optionally throwing an error if err_if_not_found is set.
I really don't want to override BaseSettings constructor, I want to leave that alone and not worry about duplicating it correctly without breaking pydantic features.
Is there a feature to be able to do something like this where I'm passing in a value to then pass along to a function or something being called inside of SettingsConfigDict:
MyConfig(err_if_not_found=True)


From my knowledge, this is not possible with Pydantic.
I believe the closest you can get to what you described is to have 2 classes, one which passes True as the flag value in the SettingsConfigDict and another which passes False. Something like:
class MyConfigBase(BaseSettings):
  ...

class MyConfigWithErrorIfNotFound(MyConfigBase):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        env_file=MyConfigs(err_if_not_found=True).configs,
        env_prefix="MY_APP",
    )

class MyConfigWithoutErrorIfNotFound(MyConfigBase):
    model_config = SettingsConfigDict(
        env_file=MyConfigs(err_if_not_found=True).configs,
        env_prefix="MY_APP",
    )

